# Running nodemon causes "Error: Cannot find module" error, but is checking the wrong path?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

I have a Node.js project where I'm using nodemon. I have a package.json script to start an Express server with nodemon, but when I run it I get an error that the module wasn't found. The package is definitely installed (I see it in /node_modules) but the error seems to be looking in the wrong directory?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "starter-weatherzen-back-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starter code for WeatherZen backend",
  "main": "src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/server.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "knex": "^0.21.12",
    "pg": "^8.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

Running "npm run start:dev" will throw an error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects_SE\course\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
> code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
> requireStack: []
> }

The actual directory of the project is:

> C:\Users\name\Desktop\Projects_SE\course\backend

with the module being installed in:

> > \backend\node_modules

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Forgot to mention in case it's relevant, but running the normal start script (npm start) runs the server just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after reading elsewhere about potential issues with having a folder in your path with spaces in its name. Even though the folder isn't directly referenced anywhere in the code, I at one point renamed a folder to include a space. After getting rid of the space, nodemon is able to be found fine. Weirdly the folder wasn't even renamed back to its original name, still different, just without a space.